# maxWInText TypoScript setting not valid for Youtube videos

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

Using TYPO3 8.7 core.

It seems TypoScript constant `styles.content.mediatext.maxWInText` is respected for Text+Media content elements that attach images, but not for Youtube videos. A large image is scaled to that maximum width. However, a Youtube video has always maximum width 480px, even if you set the maximum width larger. Has anyone experienced this issue?

I tested it over TYPO3 9.5 and 8.7 cores.

Comment: SO is no forum to verify bugs. If you think it is a bug open a ticket on forge.typo3.org

Answer (score 0):

If you use fluid Styled content:

```
tt_content.textmedia.dataProcessing.20.maxGalleryWidth = 800
tt_content.textmedia.dataProcessing.20.maxGalleryWidthInText = 600
```

Also check out

```
typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Media/Rendering/Video.html
```

You can alter it by setting the file local in your config extension.

I am not a big fan of how the media content element is implemented anno 2018, since it's not easy in combination with Fluid Styled content CSS to make the video responsive without overwriting some default CSS like .ce-gallery. That's why I often disable this content element and if video is needed make a new responsive video content element.